# Why is restarting Azure app service of the function app not syncing the azure functions?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

When deploying a azure function with zip deploy in Azure Dev Ops the time triggerd function will only work when i force a run in the azure portal.

Is there a solution how i can fix this in the deploy?

Function.json

```
{
  "generatedBy": "Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions-1.0.29",
  "configurationSource": "attributes",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "timerTrigger",
      "schedule": "%[Schedule]%",
      "useMonitor": true,
      "runOnStartup": false,
      "name": "myTimer"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false,
  "scriptFile": "../bin/[ScriptFile]",
  "entryPoint": "[entryPoint].Run"
}
```

Between [ ] is fake naming because of privacy

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I added a agentless job to the release pipeline and added the Invoke Rest API to Post a synctrigger.

Comment: Congratulations, you found a solution. Can you mark your answer as the answer to this question? This will help others.:)